# PHP create a variable using Wildcard

Tags: php, wildcard

I am trying to create a variable to set a filename knowing only the first number of characters of the filename.  I am trying to use the '*' wildcard but this does not seem to work with my statement

Using the below it is returning "failed to load external entity"

```
$file = 'TEST_REQUEST*.xml';
```

or

```
$file = 'TEST_REQUEST.*.xml';
```

How can I write the above so that it finds the file containing set prefix characters and the variable can then be used further on?

Comment: The code shown doesn't produce this error.  All this code does is assign a string value to a variable.  Are you perhaps doing something with this variable at a later time?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `glob()` to find all files matching a pattern.

```
$files = glob('TEST_REQUEST.*.xml');
if (!$files) {
  // no matching files: error handling here
  // ...
}
```

`$files` is now an array of matching filenames.  It's up to you how you handle potential multiple matches.  However, if you just want the first one you could do:

```
$file = reset($files);
// rest of your code here
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I am still getting a error when trying to call $file later;  $xml = simplexml_load_file($file);   returns a  failed to load external entity

Comment: Just before your call to `simplexml_load_file($file);`, I suggest you add a `var_dump($file);` and check what that variable contains

Comment: Thanks Rob, tried that and it returns; bool(false)
Warning: simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity

Comment: So your `$file` variable is empty (or more strictly speaking, it is `false`).  Either a) no filenames matched your pattern (did you implement any error handling as suggested?), or b) the value of `$file` has been modified between when you loaded it and when you tried to use it

Comment: I suggest you add a `var_dump($files);` just after the call to `glob()` to check what's matching (or not matching) your pattern

Comment: Thanks Rob.  var_dump($files) returning array(0) { } however file & pattern is in directory.  If I remove glob() and set the full file name as the variable it identifies and assigns file.

Comment: Please share the exact filename and the pattern you're using (that's should match it but isn't)

Comment: The exact filename = ABC_SEND_REQUEST_20221130T16584056_20221130 (XML File Type).  It resides in the same folder/directory as the php file.

Comment: Hi Rob, I have this working now.  I was wrapping the filename in single ' rather than ".  Final updated code that worked - $files = glob("ABC_SEND_REQUEST*.xml");
$file = reset($files); Thank you all very much for your help with this topic :)